# Android webview don't scroll in 2.3 but it work in 3.0 and 4.0

Tags: android, scroll, android-webview

I have a problem with a webview.

Its load an url similar to this:

```
<html>
   <head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/></head>
   <body>
     <div id="header"></div>
     <div id="scrollable-content"><!--a lot of stuff inside here--></div>
     <div id="footer"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

"scrollable-content" has overflown-y = auto in css(i also tried overflown-y=scroll) and nothing

I cant scroll in android 2.3, for what i read it is becouse of the meta viewport. But i cant take it off becouse it is beeing used for responsive design

Any ideas?

Comment: try this https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/ui/WebView.java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the solution:

http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/scroll-div.htm

overflown do not work in android 2.0