# Scrolling divs on android devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I can not make a scrolling div on android 2.3. Is there any trick to do it with html and css code? If not, how can I do it with javascript or jquery?

http://jsfiddle.net/3WbP8/

Here is my html code and I want to make scrollable the `subcategories_div` div.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with what you got so far.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you cannot make a scrolling div on Android 2.x - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778697/android-webview-dont-scroll-in-2-3-but-it-work-in-3-0-and-4-0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013204/android-browser-bug-div-overflow-scrolling).

For how to make a scrolling div on android 3.x and up, see [here.](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/scroll-div.htm) There is also a javascript based example (touchscroll.js), but I have not personally tried it on 2.3 and below.